# Wordpress on Apache - Pageload Increased up to 30 Sec. - How to Debug?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, wordpress, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I running a Wordpress Theme on a Google Compute Engine with Cloud SQL and Apache2 (W3 Total Cache which is off at the Moment). Actually no Visitors than me because it´s in development.

The Problem start from nearly nothing. I was developing on the website when the Pageload start to Increase. But that could´t be the failure because I undo everything I did. The CPU climb up from 1-5% to 80% on 10 Processes coming Apache.

In the last days it goes back to 1-5% but the Pageload is still taking approximately 30 Sec.

I installed mod_status to see the actual connections. But don´t know how i move forward now.
Is there a way to Debug what is causing the huge Pageload?

Here are some configs.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    ServerName my-domain.com
    ServerAlias my-domain.de
    ServerAlias my-domain.co.uk
    ServerAlias my-domain.fr
    ServerAlias my-domain.es

<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status

Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Allow from .foo.com
</Location> 

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
#       AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

error.log (just showing that sometimes)

```
zend_mm_heap corrupted
[Fri Feb 06 12:55:21 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Feb 06 12:55:22 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u14 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

and this yesterday but not the last time. Maybe I already fixed that ...

[Thu Feb 05 20:49:54 2015] [error] [client 92.225.106.196] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

server-status (sorry to big for display correctly also i x.x.x.x. my ip´s)

```
    Srv PID Acc M   CPU     SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client  VHost   Request
0-0 9225    0/42/159    _   13.58   25  10230   0.0 0.75    1.69    x.x.x.x my-domain.com   POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1423231749.3968889713287353
1-0 9377    0/0/121 W   0.00    11  0   0.0 0.00    3.17    x.x.x.x     my-domain.com   POST /vop/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?app_media_manager=1 HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/173 .   13.35   20  0   0.0 0.00    2.83    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
3-0 9130    0/47/148    _   22.36   22  11045   0.0 0.63    1.31    x.x.x.x my-domain.com   POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1423231751.5135180950164794
4-0 9236    0/56/222    _   11.30   13  447 0.0 2.44    6.26    x.x.x.x my-domain.com   GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/01/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1
5-0 9237    0/37/120    _   14.69   26  1   0.0 0.75    1.68    x.x.x.x my-domain.com   NULL
6-0 9238    0/63/131    _   11.29   22  27297   0.0 0.61    3.93    x.x.x.x my-domain.com   GET / HTTP/1.1
7-0 9378    0/2/168 _   0.00    5   1   0.0 0.00    2.80    x.x.x.x     my-domain.com   NULL
8-0 -   0/0/121 .   0.00    1024    0   0.0 0.00    1.46    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
9-0 9045    0/85/135    _   20.94   15  1   0.0 0.47    3.57    x.x.x.x my-domain.com   NULL
10-0    -   0/0/91  .   9.42    12  0   0.0 0.00    1.45    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
11-0    -   0/0/82  .   43.88   1445    0   0.0 0.00    0.77    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
12-0    8996    0/63/73 W   29.47   5   0   0.0 2.17    2.63    x.x.x.x     my-domain.com   GET / HTTP/1.1
13-0    -   0/0/78  .   27.96   1011    0   0.0 0.00    2.25    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
14-0    -   0/0/61  .   25.47   1014    1   0.0 0.00    1.25    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
15-0    -   0/0/41  .   40.80   1047    0   0.0 0.00    0.18    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
16-0    -   0/0/10  .   0.00    1771    0   0.0 0.00    0.15    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
17-0    -   0/0/15  .   18.70   1492    0   0.0 0.00    0.31    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
18-0    -   0/0/9   .   0.00    3728    0   0.0 0.00    0.00    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
19-0    -   0/0/11  .   10.47   3706    0   0.0 0.00    1.00    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
20-0    -   0/0/12  .   8.83    3909    0   0.0 0.00    0.00    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
21-0    -   0/0/9   .   10.56   3888    0   0.0 0.00    0.00    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
22-0    -   0/0/39  .   15.21   3721    0   0.0 0.00    0.92    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
23-0    -   0/0/8   .   8.80    3931    0   0.0 0.00    0.21    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
24-0    8488    0/203/203   W   73.61   0   0   0.0 5.83    5.83    x.x.x.x my-domain.com   GET /server-status?refresh=N HTTP/1.1
25-0    -   0/0/10  .   7.91    3890    0   0.0 0.00    0.15    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
26-0    -   0/0/3   .   2.33    4258    0   0.0 0.00    0.00    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
27-0    -   0/0/3   .   0.00    4286    0   0.0 0.00    0.00    127.0.0.1   my-domain.com   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
```

The access.log is just showing the POST and GET results from the plugins, but I think there is nothing important.

Maybe it´s important to mention that the initial request is taking long!
When I do a Pageload the first request takes that long, when it´s done it´s fast.

[image]

Is there a way to Tool to Debug my PHP-Code, MySQL Queries or Javascript (Browserdebugger for java I guess right?)?

p.s.: When I activate "W3 Total Cache" the first request and the hole page-load goes like charm, but I need to work at the Wordpress-Backend and on developing it´s also no fun to wait that long..

Comment: Have you considered the server itself, and if a shared server - "noisy neighbours" consuming the resources?

Comment: It´s not a shared server as far as i understand the google compute engine. I am running a virtual machine instance but i thought the full power is mine. it´s the same issue when i start another vm-instance. Is there a way to trace the first request and what exactly happen there? it maybe looks like a redirecting problem?!?

Comment: Yes the way I would confirm whether its the server or not is deploy the site to another machine. I had your situation - I had a wordpress site **that was cached - WP super cache** loading in 15-30+  seconds. moved the site to better hosting - now the **uncached** site loads in less than 1sec

Comment: forgot to say, when i activate "W3 Total Cache" it´s comming up in 2 Sec. but that´s not usable for developing and to work in the Backend is not fun either.. and their has to be something wrong, because it works before pretty well.

Comment: There are many tools out there to debug performance on your machine. While you provided a lot of bytes in your question, they are mostly irrelevant. Your question is "how can I monitor/debug performance?" and there are many possible answers. Flagged as too broad. Just google around and try to learn how to debug/profile your PHP code.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? If so please help the community by posting an answer. The [Stackdriver agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#agent) and the Apache [plugin](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/apache) can add visibility over your VM to help troubleshoot this kind of issues.